# Define session variable in c# get it from javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, session

I'm saving string that represents the URL in a session variable from my code behind like this:

```
        String mois = Request.QueryString["mois"].ToString();
        String m = mois;


        String moisnom = Request.QueryString["moisnom"].ToString();
        String annee = Request.QueryString["annee"].ToString();
        String dt = Request.QueryString["date"].ToString();
        String user = Request.QueryString["user"].ToString();
        String where = "jour.aspx?mois=" + mois + "&moisnom=" + moisnom + "&annee=" + annee + "&date=" + dt + "&user=" + user + "&cp=all" + "&usl=" + Request.QueryString["usl"].ToString();
        Session["togo"] = where;
```

And then I try to get it like this in JavaScript like this:

```
    var togo = '<%=Session["togo"]%>';
    //  i also tried this var togo ='@Session["togo"]'; 
    var newPage = togo; // this should contain a string with the url to go to
```

But when I use it it uses it as a string here is what my URL looks like:

```
http://localhost:50311/<%=Session["togo"]%>
 or
http://localhost:50311/@Session["togo"]
```

How else can I access the session variable or what am I doing wrong please?

```
 EDIT: 
like you suggested i already tried using the hidden field like this 

     yes  i tried that but then i had this problem here is the definition of the hidden field  

             <input type="hidden" value="aa" id="myHiddenVar" runat="server"/>
```

then i tried giving it the value i need on click

```
            String where = "jour.aspx?mois=" + mois + "&moisnom=" + moisnom + "&annee=" + annee + "&date=" + dt + "&user=" + user + "&cp=all" + "&usl=" + Request.QueryString["usl"].ToString();
        myHiddenVar.Value= where;
```

and this is how i tried getting it from the js file

```
       var togo = $('#myHiddenVar').val();
       var newPage = togo;
```

but it takes the default value meaning "aa" as in value="aa" i gues cause the script is  executed  before the assignment of the variable any way how to reverse that order ?

Comment: Is that javascript in a separate js file? The asp.net specific syntax (`<% .. %>`) does not work there, only in files (aspx, ascx, cshtml) that are processed by the asp.net engine.

Comment: yes its in a js file  do u know any links on how to get the session variables from a js file fuction please ?

Comment: if it is in different js file than you cant access it <%xyz%> i.e scriplet tags only work on aspx page...

Comment: just remove the value parameter from your aspx page...dont assign anything!! assign value from code behind...

Comment: Yeah now it will work!! Just edit value attribute of hidden tag Value="0 " .Even you can remove value attribute

Comment: yes when i remove it it doesnt work and when i replace it with Value="0 " 
it just shows  http://localhost:50311/0

Answer (score 1):

After Session["togo"] = where; 
save this Session["togo"] in hidden variable

hiddenVariable= Session["togo"];

Now in JS access that hiddenvariable:
suppose ID of hiddenvariable is "hdnxyz"

var togo = $('#hdnxyz').val();

var newPage = togo;

Comment: Yeah now it will work!!
 
Just edit value attribute of hidden tag
Value="0 " .Even you can remove value attribute

Comment: yes it worked but it takes the value assigned by default not the ne i want

Comment: Dont assign the default value to it ,okay?

Comment: okay then make JS function and inside that function do ur stuff of accesing the hideenvarible

Answer (score 1):

first of all session resides on server!!!!!!

If it is in different js file than you cant access it <%xyz%> i.e scriplet tags only work on aspx page...

so there is no way to access the session variable on client side..

instead assign your sessio9n value to a hidden variable and then access it using javascript

Answer (score 0):

Write Session element in a `asp:HiddenField` and then read from it with your js code.